# Is there any way to hide tray icons? 17.10(like skype, steam etc)

Tags: 17.10

I'd like to hide some, but not all apps. [I'm talking about these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urePk.png)

Comment: Why not just go into the settings for those individual applications and set it so that they don't show tray icons?

Comment: most apps don't have this setting.

Comment: Well Skype and Steam definitely do.

Comment: @user364819 I couldn't find this option. Can you tell me where it is?